# fusionchart xt how to show different place title

Tags: fusioncharts

I want to show level value of chart in type : MSCombiDY2D in fusionchart XT

How can I show differently placed data? Ex : -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Values for the line dataset can be positioned below by setting "valuePosition" as "Below" in the respective dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I tried working on your problem, and have probably come up to a solution. I hope it will be helpful for you. For any further issues try out - [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/4REJ5/)

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
            var salesAnlysisChart = new FusionCharts({
                type: 'mscombi2d',
                renderAt: 'chart-container',
                width: '400',
                height: '300',
                dataFormat: 'json',
                dataSource: {
                    "chart": {
                        "caption": "National Average",
                        "numberPrefix": "",
                        "showBorder": "0",
                        "showValues": "0",
                        "paletteColors": "#00FFFF,#FFFF00,#f2c500",
                        "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                        "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                        "canvasBgColor": "#ffffff",
                        "captionFontSize": "14",
                        "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                        "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                        "divlineColor": "#999999",
                        "divLineIsDashed": "1",
                        "divLineDashLen": "1",
                        "divLineGapLen": "1",
                        "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                        "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                        "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                        "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                        "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                        "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                        "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                        "toolTipPadding": "5",
                        "legendBgColor": "#ffffff",
                        "legendBorderAlpha": '0',
                        "legendShadow": '0',
                        "legendItemFontSize": '10',
                        "legendItemFontColor": '#666666'
                    },
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "category": [
                                {
                                    "label": "1"
                    },
                                {
                                    "label": "2"
                    },
                                {
                                    "label": "3"
                    },
                                {
                                    "label": "4"
                    },
                                {
                                    "label": "5"
                    },
                                {
                                    "label": "6"
                    },
                                {
                                    "label": "7"
                    },
                                {
                                    "label": "8"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
                    "dataset": [
                        {
                            "seriesName": "Column",
                            "showValues": "1",
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "value": "100"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "100"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "100"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "100"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "100"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "100"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "100"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "99"
                    }
                ]
            },
                        {
                            "seriesName": "Line",
                            "renderAs": "line",
                            "showValues": "1",
                            "data": [
                                {
                                    "value": "14"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "1"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "5"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "3"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "10"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "98"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "3"
                    },
                                {
                                    "value": "23"
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
                }
            }).render();
        });
```